# How to toggle a button in jQuery on click event

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, button, togglebutton

Sorry if this beginner question, but I have some *jQuery* to Hide fields in SharePoint that works fine but now I am wanting to *toggle* (hide/show) when the user clicks a *button*.  I feel like I am close but can't get the syntax right.

I am pretty certain it is the `$("input[toggleButton]).click(function()` that I am messing up.  Any thoughts would be great.

```
<style type="text/css">
#toggleButton {
margin-top:10px;
padding-right:20px;
text-align:right;
}
</style>

<br/>

<input type="button" class="toggleButton" value="Show/Hide All Fields" id="toggleButton">


<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("input[toggleButton]).click(function()

{
$("nobr:contains('Approved By')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').toggle();
$("nobr:contains('Assigned To:')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').toggle();
$("nobr:contains('Request Status')").parent('h3').parent('td').parent('tr').toggle();
});
});

</script>
```

Comment: A double quote is missing in your example. Just in case you didn't notice it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
$(".toggleButton").click(function(){
    ...
});
```

Comment: This works very well thanks, is there a property that will set these to hide by default.  I had attempted "false" with no luck.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am calling #toggleButton directly in $().

http://jsfiddle.net/agdm/fQhDh/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toggleButton').click(function() {
    $("td:contains('Approved By')").parent().toggle();
    $("td:contains('Assigned To')").parent().toggle();
    $("td:contains('Request Status')").parent().toggle();
  });
});
```

Also as per: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/nobr

"The nobr element has good support in modern browsers (for backwards-compatibility reasons) but should not be used."

Answer (score 0):

When selecting an element with jQuery you use CSS selectors. When using an element name and square brackets like you did, you are using an attribute selector. It looks like this for example:

```
$("a[title]"); // Select all <a> elements with the title attribute set to whatever value 
$("a[title=foobar]"); // Select all <a> elements with the title attribute set to "foobar"
```

The button you defined in markup has a class name and an ID set. Because selecting by a class name could return multiple elements I would go with the ID because its always unique. You can select elements by ID by using "#" like this:

```
$("#id"); // Will return only one element
```

You can select elements of a given class by using "." like this:

```
$(".className"); // Could return multiple elements
```

This document explains the use of selectors in CSS: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

I don't think that your event handler for the button click event is called, because the selector seems to be wrong. This one should work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#toggleButton").click(function() {
        // Do something
    });

});
```